# Error with getting information in the request body in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql

I want to send information from frontend to backend via axios, so i'm send the informaiton via the post request and trying to get it in the backend via request body.
But im just getting error and i don't understand why this is happening ?
Error One : Cross origin request block
Error Two : Uncought in Promise ( no further information just long link )

My code so far :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Task from "./Task";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = async (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/message", { todos })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    /** */
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
    /** */
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/message");
      setMessage(res.data);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  }; //#endregion

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <Task todo={todo} key={key} myKey={key} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {message.map((e) => (
        <div>{e.todo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Client } = require("pg");
const client = new Client({
  user: "jj",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "dbname",
  password: "rootuser",
  port: 5432,
});
client.connect();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const { rows } = await client.query(`SELECT * from todo`);
  res.send(rows);
});

app.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const { todos } = req.body;
  console.log(todos);
  res.send("POST request to the homepage");
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5174.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think first error is CORS error. In order to handle it, you should use cors package in server(link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
2. When it comes to second one, I think that error come from `fetchProducts` functions. It means there is a error in get request but you are not catching it (obviously CORS error). therefore that problem arises. use try/catch inside `fetchProducts` function or use promise or callbacks.